# Command line arguments and the length of the command line argument array

Tags: java, arrays, command-line-arguments

This is the question which I got "Write a program to read and display 2 command line arguments and the length of the command line argument array."

This is my answer in Java..Is this correct ?

```
    int length = args.length;

        for(int i = 0;i<length; i++)
            {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
            }
System.out.println("Length is " + args.length);
}
```

Comment: yeah it's correct, the args is coming from `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: Your program reads the entire command line array. You should read only the first 2 so your code is not correct. Also, on some environments the first command line argument is the program name. You didn't specify the language. Is that Java?

Comment: to know for future, you should post code review questions to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks all..it's functioning correctly now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only display 2 arguments?

```
for(int i = 0; i< args.length && i < 2; i++)
{
  System.out.println(args[i]);
}
System.out.println("Length is " + args.length);
```